Correctly configure a release build - once per project or in all modules?
I've created my first Android project with two modules (:app and :additionalModule).
Now I want to create a release build with isMinifyEnabled = true and all these things. Do I have to configure that in each module (build.gradle.kts of each module) or only once in the project build.gradle.kts or maybe only once in my "main" (:app with MainActivity) module?

Actual minification step is happening only in your application module.
Library modules can provide required R8/ProGuard configuration using consumer-rules.pro file.
You need to enable R8/ProGuard only in your :app module.
Thus, you should keep isMinifyEnabled = true only in your :app module.
